# Puzzeled about BindingList as ComboBox data source

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

Given a very simple setup: A ComboBox shall be populated by a `BindingList<string>`. Obviously, the `SelectedValueChanged` and `SelectedIndexChanged` events are of major importance. But they both behave very strange:

1. **The list is initially empty.**
2. **On adding the first item**, I receive two consecutive `SelectedValueChanged` events. Why are there two events instead of one, even though the value reported does not change between these two events? At the same time, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is missing, even though the index just changed from -1 to 0.
3. **Adding additional items**. Now, I receive one single `SelectedValueChanged` event for each item added, even though the selected value actually stays the same. No `SelectedIndexChanged` events, though. But this is expected as the selected index does not change here.
4. **Removing an item from the end of the list**. I keep getting `SelectedValueChanged` events even though no actual change happens. I do not see `SelectedIndexChanged` events, though.
5. **Removing the last item (which is actually still the selected one)**. Now I get both, `SelectedValueChanged` and `SelectedIndexChanged`, as I would expect it.
6. **Adding a new item again**. Now it gets really weird. The item is added and as it is the only item in the list it is selected. The ComboBox reports it as expected (`SelectedValue` is "Item 1" and `SelectedIndex` is 0). But now I do not receive any Changed events, neither for the value nor for the index.
7. **Adding more items**. I don't get the (non-expected) `SelectecValueChanged` events which I received on adding items to the initial list (step 3).

As I don't expect SELECT to be broken, please point me to what I'm missing here.

Please note (regarding the answer of @Alex Horlock): In this sample, the ComboBox selection is only affected by adding/removing items to/from the data source. Changing the selected item in the ComboBox interactively behaves as expected.

Here's the code for the sample Form1 (containing a ComboBox and three Buttons (Add/Remove/Status):

```
namespace BindingTest
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingList<string>();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dataSource = comboBox1.DataSource as BindingList<string>;
            dataSource?.Add($"Item {dataSource.Count + 1}");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dataSource = comboBox1.DataSource as BindingList<string>;
            if (dataSource?.Count > 0)
            {
                dataSource.Remove(dataSource.Last());
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"SelectedValue: {comboBox1.SelectedValue}");
            Console.WriteLine($"SelectedIndex: {comboBox1.SelectedIndex}");
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dataSource = comboBox1.DataSource as BindingList<string>;
            Console.WriteLine($"SelectedINDEXChanged: {comboBox1.SelectedIndex} [{dataSource?.Count}]");
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dataSource = comboBox1.DataSource as BindingList<string>;
            Console.WriteLine($"SelectedVALUEChanged: {comboBox1.SelectedValue} [{dataSource?.Count}]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, SELECT seems to be broken here. Deep in the ComboBox code, there is a private flag named `selectedValueChangedFired`, which is not properly reset when the list got empty and a new item is added to it. It is only reset upon user interaction with the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET Framework code for ComboBox maintains a private flag storing information about the change events being already fired. This flag is only reset if it finds the data source implementing `ICurrencyManagerProvider`. Unfortunately, `BindingList<T>` does not implement this interface. Good news is that `BindingSource` does implement it. So all I had to do was to place a `BindingSource` in between the ComboBox and the `BindingList<T>`, like this:

- I've simply dropped a `BindingSource` from the toolbox onto the form.
- In the form's constructor, I replaced

  ```
  comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingList<string>();
  ```

  with

  ```
  bindingSource1.DataSource = new BindingList<string>();
  comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
  ```

This does the trick.

There are still a number of duplicate and irrelevant events fired. However, this solutions is firing events in step 6, which used to be the show stopper in the original version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why all those events fire in that order but I think you want to use the selectionChangeCommitted event to avoid this type of issue.

See - (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `SelectionChangeCommitted` seems only to be fired if the selection is changed interactively. Here, the selection is changed merely by adding and removing items to/from the data source. Interactive changes fire the correct events, anyway.